# ¿Cómo ejecutar funciones de Javascript en Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, aplicación-web

Estoy tratando de trabajar con código Javascript en un proyecto de Google Apps Script. He visto que puedo crear un archivo .html con el código Javascript. Como éste:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body
        <script>
          function prueba(){
            //code
          }
  
          function prueba2(){
            //code
          }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Entonces quiero saber:

1. si es posible ejecutar funciones en ese código y devolver valores de esas funciones al archivo .gs;
2. Si tengo que codificar la parte .html como si fuera un usuario destinado al usuario final

Usaré el archivo .gs para escribir información (recuperada de Netsuite) en un archivo de hoja de cálculo de Google, pero ya he hecho esa parte.

Comment: Cualquier función se puede ejecutar o declarar en `prueba()` y `prueba2()` y uno de los dos puede llamar a la otra función y aplicar

Comment: Lee https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web y https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html. Si requieres mayor orientación agrega una [mcve].

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.